# Oracle differences of local index and local index with partition keyword

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-partitioning

I found [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/partitioned-tables-and-indexes) tutorial about different indeces in Oracle.
I was wondering, if someone could explain the differences between the those three create index-statements:

```
CREATE INDEX invoices_idx ON invoices (invoice_date);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX invoices_idx ON invoices (invoice_date) LOCAL;
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX invoices_idx ON invoices (invoice_date) LOCAL
 (PARTITION invoices_q1 TABLESPACE users,
  PARTITION invoices_q2 TABLESPACE users,
  PARTITION invoices_q3 TABLESPACE users,
  PARTITION invoices_q4 TABLESPACE users);
```

I would have assumed, that all create the same type of local index on each partition.

//EDIT:
another question.
let's assume I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE invoices
(invoice_no    NUMBER NOT NULL,
 invoice_date  DATE   NOT NULL,
 comments      VARCHAR2(500))
PARTITION BY RANGE (invoice_date)
(PARTITION invoices_q1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/04/2001', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users,
 PARTITION invoices_q2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/07/2001', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users,
 PARTITION invoices_q3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/09/2001', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users,
 PARTITION invoices_q4 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/01/2002', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) TABLESPACE users);
```

and I create an index with:

```
CREATE INDEX invoices_idx ON invoices (invoice_date);
```

what type of index would that be and what type of index would I need if i query also on e.g. invoice_no only?

Thanks for the clarification.
E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX invoices_idx ON invoices (invoice_date);
```

You are creating a global index. The docs says that a "global index  can be partitioned by the range or hash method, and it can be defined on any type of partitioned, or non-partitioned, table".

```
CREATE INDEX invoices_idx ON invoices (invoice_date) LOCAL;
```

You are creating a local index. A local index is a one-to-one mapping between a index partition and a table partition.

```
CREATE INDEX invoices_idx ON invoices (invoice_date) LOCAL
 (PARTITION invoices_q1 TABLESPACE users,
  PARTITION invoices_q2 TABLESPACE users,
  PARTITION invoices_q3 TABLESPACE users,
  PARTITION invoices_q4 TABLESPACE users);
```

You are creating a local partitioned index. Local partitioned indexes allow us to take individual partitions of a table and indexes offline for maintenance (or reorganization) without affecting the other partitions and indexes in the table.

Answer (score 6):

If you create the index `LOCAL` then each partition has its "own" index. Otherwise you have a kind of "one big index" spanning entire table called `GLOBAL` index.

There is even a third option, you can partitionize also an index. `LOCAL` means, the index partition are the same like the base table. However, it is possible to partitionize the index different than the table - but I have to admit, that I don't know any use case where it would make sense.

Usually `LOCAL` indexes are better because

- The index partition is smaller (thus faster) to scan compared to one big index
- The index does not get invalid when you drop/truncate a partition
- You can build the index only on certain partitions instead for the entire table.

But of course there are also drawback

- If you need a UNIQUE index and the partition key-column is not part of your index then it must be a GLOBAL one
- If you have many partitions and your query does not specify the partition then a LOCAL index could be slower because scanning many local index partitions is like scanning many different indexes.